# UITableViewHeaderFooterView drawing incorrectly

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a table view with the usual stuff plugged in, the issue is in UITableViewHeaderFooterView, when they appear first they have unusual frame. But if i scroll down and back up(once they are reused) they appear fine. Here is the relevant code.

EDIT: The table view cells on the other hand appear fine.

The log for headerView at this line
FAQSectionHeaderView *headerView = [self.tableView dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:@"HeaderView"];
shows this:

```
2013-11-01 15:16:04.716 FAQDetail[27576:70b] header View <FAQSectionHeaderView: 0x8b582e0; baseClass = UITableViewHeaderFooterView; frame = (0 0; 0 0); text = ''; layer = <CALayer: 0x8b58420>> at Section 0
2013-11-01 15:16:04.718 FAQDetail[27576:70b] header View <FAQSectionHeaderView: 0xa83edc0; baseClass = UITableViewHeaderFooterView; frame = (0 0; 0 0); text = ''; layer = <CALayer: 0xa83ee80>> at Section 1
2013-11-01 15:16:04.719 FAQDetail[27576:70b] header View <FAQSectionHeaderView: 0x8c2f8e0; baseClass = UITableViewHeaderFooterView; frame = (0 0; 0 0); text = ''; layer = <CALayer: 0x8c2c370>> at Section 2
2013-11-01 15:16:04.719 FAQDetail[27576:70b] header View <FAQSectionHeaderView: 0x8a3f7a0; baseClass = UITableViewHeaderFooterView; frame = (0 0; 0 0); text = ''; layer = <CALayer: 0x8a3f860>> at Section 3
2013-11-01 15:16:04.720 FAQDetail[27576:70b] header View <FAQSectionHeaderView: 0x8c70dc0; baseClass = UITableViewHeaderFooterView; frame = (0 0; 0 0); text = ''; layer = <CALayer: 0x8c6f0b0>> at Section 4
```

in ViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
[self.tableView registerClass:[FAQSectionHeaderView class] forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier:@"HeaderView"];
[self.tableView registerClass:[FAQDetailCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
}
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{

FAQSectionHeaderView *headerView = [self.tableView dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:@"HeaderView"];

[headerView setupWithQuestion:[self.sectionTitleArray objectAtIndex:section]];

return headerView;

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath      *)indexPath
{
if (self.selectedSection == indexPath.section) {

FAQDetailCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

[cell initWithAnswer:[self.rowsTitleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]];

return cell;
} else
    return nil;

}
```

in FAQSectionHeaderView.m (subclass of UITableViewHeaderFooterView)

```
-(void)setupWithQuestion: (NSString *)question{
[self.questionLabel removeFromSuperview];

CGSize expectedLabelHeight = [FAQSectionHeaderView sizeForQuestion:question];

self.questionLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];

self.questionLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, self.frame.size.width-20, expectedLabelHeight.height);

NSMutableAttributedString *q = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[@"Q " stringByAppendingString:question]];

[q addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor redColor] range:NSMakeRange(0, 2)];

[q addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14] range:NSMakeRange(0, question.length)];


[q addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:17] range:NSMakeRange(0, 2)];

[self.questionLabel setAttributedText:q];

self.questionLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17];

self.questionLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
[self addSubview:self.questionLabel];


self.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.questionLabel.frame.size.height+20);

}

-(void)prepareForReuse{

[self.questionLabel removeFromSuperview];

}
```

Here is how it appears initially and after cell reuse kicks in.
[image] [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the frame is being set to (0,0,0,0) unlike tableViewCell which automatically sets the frame,

Manually setting the frame does the trick.

```
FAQSectionHeaderView *headerView = [self.tableView dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:@"HeaderView"];

if (headerView == nil) {
//This never gets called, even though it should according to documentation.
    headerView = [[FAQSectionHeaderView alloc] init];
}

headerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tableView.frame.size.width, [FAQSectionHeaderView sizeForQuestion:[self.sectionTitleArray objectAtIndex:section]].height+20);
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier: always returns a view if you have called the registerClass:forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: method elsewhere (which you did).

One issue I see in your code above is that after you obtain a header view from the dequeue method, you call a custom initializer (i.e., initWithQuestion:). You shouldn't initialize an object twice. The first initializer was called implicitly by the dequeue method, i.e., the header view's init method was called by the framework.

Comment: thanks for looking into it, but I am not initializing the object in the initWithQuestion call, it's more like a setupWithQuestion: (method implementation is included above), I don't do any init activity there. Did you face the issue that it returns the object with frame CGRectZero?